# Android GeoCoder Service Not Available Error

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

The topic appears to have been raised many times here on *StackOverflow,* but they're all quite dated. I'm asking again in case the requirements have since changed, and if it has become a paid-service.

My app utilizes a Google map with markers, and everything works well. The API key has been included and the map markers update as expected. However, I would also like to insert the addresses into the map markers and have discovered that this is achieved through the use of the **GeoCoder.** I have tried many examples but it's all failing with the **SERVICE NOT AVAILABLE** error. Here's one from the *Ray Wenderlich* site:

```
fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng): String {

    val geocoder = Geocoder(this)
    val addresses: List<Address>?
    val address: Address?
    var addressText = ""

    try {

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)

        if (null != addresses && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            address = addresses[0]
            for (i in 0 until address.maxAddressLineIndex) {
                addressText += if (i == 0) address.getAddressLine(i) else "\n" + address.getAddressLine(i)
            }
        }

    } catch (e: IOException) {

        Log.e("GeoCoder", e.localizedMessage)  // ==> throws "Service not Available"

    }

    return addressText
}
```

In my *Google Developer Console,* I found a **GeoCoding API** which is not enabled.

**Q1.** Is this required simply for converting latitude/longitude coordinates into a street address?

**Q2.** Does this mean that every street address lookup is chargeable as indicated in the pricing table?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** Is this required simply for converting latitude/longitude coordinates into a street address?

**A:** Yes, but feel free to choose any alternative you find on internet. Right now, I can't find anything unfortunately, which is completely free

**Q2.** Does this mean that every street address lookup is chargeable as indicated in the pricing table?

**A:** Yes

Go here at https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

Click on Places, and check out the pricing yourself
 [image: Google geocode pricing]